# jQuery click handler with .toggle() does not work with datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have some datatables inside divs and I want to ".toggle()" the tables to hide or show them by clicking on an image (which works).  After datatables initialization, my click handler still fires every time, but $(this) is only correct on the last element.  On every other element $(this) is 'prevObject' which doesn't work with .toggle().

```
<div class='toggle'>
  <img src='/some/path/foo.jpg'>
  <table class='dt'>
     ...
  </table>
</div>
<div class='toggle'>
  <img src='/some/path/foo.jpg'>
  <table class='dt'>
     ...
  </table>
</div>
<div class='toggle'>
  <img src='/some/path/foo.jpg'>
  <table class='dt'>
     ...
  </table>
</div>

//This works if I don't initialize datatables
$(".toggle").on("click", "img", function(event) {
    $(this).siblings(".dt").toggle();
});
```

Any idea what is going on with $(this)?

EDIT: The jQuery selector "$(this)" above works fine if datatables are not initialized.  After initialization "$(this)" returns "prevObject" on all, but one of the elements.  Therefore one element works properly when clicked and all the rest do not.

EDIT2: Here is a jsfiddle to illustrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/S6bhL/10/

EDIT3: In my actual app I had to end up using the solution below with the following modifications:

```
$(this).parent().parent().find(".dt");
$(this).parent().parent().find(".dataTables_wrapper");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Since OP updated the question, Here is my updated answer.

[UPDATED JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/S6bhL/12/)

Looks like, whenever you're clicking to init datatables, it is being wrapped by a div `dataTables_wrapper`. So handling both the cases.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".toggle").on("click", "img", function (event) {
        var $nextDT = $(this).next('.dt');
        var $nextDTWrap = $(this).next('.dataTables_wrapper');

        if ($nextDT.length) {
            $nextDT.toggle();
        } else if ($nextDTWrap.length) {
            $nextDTWrap.toggle();
        }
    });
});

function doit() {
    $(".dt").each(function () {
        $(this).dataTable();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  My actual code was correct, but I have updated the question as you suggested.

Comment: I have table data, but for the sake of brevity I put "..." in the example.

Comment: You should include original markup in your question. Sometimes, dummy markup doesn't help. Did you look at my DEMO? Is that not what you want?

Comment: It is exactly what I want, but it won't work if datatables are initialized.  After datatables are initialized the jquery selector returns "prevObject" on all but one of the elements.

Comment: @user3091850 - glad this solution worked. also please upvote if the answer is helpful.